# Can't Access stylesheet through partial in Node Express App (handlebars)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'd admit I am relatively new to node in general, and I am stuck on this issue in regards to being able to use a style sheet within a partial.

This is my file structure

app.js

public

- images
- javascripts
- stylesheets

  - style.css

views

- layouts

  - main.hbs
- partials

  - head.hbs
  - navbar.hbs
- error.hbs
- index.hbs

I made sure to include this within my app.js and also required the path module.

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'public')));
```

This my link to my stylesheet within my head.hbs partial.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/stylesheets/style.css">
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/stylesheets/style.css">
```

try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
```

(without `/public/`)

Currently you are telling `express.static` to look for a file in: `/public/public/stylesheets/style.css`.

Comment: The path is I have is right based on my editor's code completion.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, are you saying that the path is correct?

Comment: Yes. I have to have "/public/stylesheets.." instead of just "/stylesheets..".

Comment: Are you sure? the default express-generated handlebars app uses the same `express.static`, but links to stylesheets like I showed (not like the method in your question).

Comment: Figured it out. Had to use add  `\public` as my first parameter in my app.use method.